# Compare two labels from different rows in swift

Tags: ios, swift

say me, please, how better compare two same (label has name "labelNumber") labels from different rows in Tableview

For example: I know, that in row №0 label is "06" (Int) and in next cell (row №1) this label is "07". So, "07" > "06". How compare it with swift language?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't compare label values (view), compare the property values in the data source (model)

Comment: Also, comparing integers and booleans is much more efficient than comparing strings.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to compare label values, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The wrong way

As stated by *@vadian*, you should NOT use the UI you populated to perform calculations on data.

However this is the code to compare the values inside 2 `UITableViewCell(s)`

```
class Controller: UITableViewController {

    func equals(indexA: NSIndexPath, indexB: NSIndexPath) -> Bool? {
        guard let
            cellA = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexA),
            cellB = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexB) else { return nil }

        return cellA.textLabel?.text == cellB.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```

### The right way

Think about how you are populating the cells. I imagine you are using some Model Value. So just compare the Model Values you are using to populate the cells.

Probably something like this

```
class Controller: UITableViewController {

    var data: [Int] = [] // ....

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCellID") else { fatalError("No cell found with this id: 'YourCellID'")}
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func equals(indexA: NSIndexPath, indexB: NSIndexPath) -> Bool? {
        return data[indexA.row] == data[indexB.row]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the values stored within your data array:

```
if dataArray[0].myIntegerValue > dataArray[1].myIntegerValue {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Edit: this assumes your data is stored as objects with that Int as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, don't do that. In the MVC design pattern, labels are views. They are for displaying data, not storing it.

Trying to read values from table view labels is especially bad, because as the table view scrolls, the cells that go off-screen will be recycled and the values in their views will be discarded. You need to save your data to a model object. (An array works just fine to save table view data, or an array of arrays for a sectioned table view.)