# Comparing values in two cells

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableview showing data like so...

[image]

Now I want to check if 123 > 60, if 60 > 66, if 66 > 85 and so on for all the data. How can I thus compare the values in different cells..?

Did go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560866/compare-two-labels-from-different-rows-in-swift) link. But couldn't make much out of it..

**EDIT 1: This is the few lines I've mentioned in `cellforRowAt..`**

```
    let fitnessData = fitnessDetails[indexPath.row]
    cell.dateLabel.text = fitnessData.date
    cell.dataLabel.text = fitnessData.value
```

Comment: Compare your data array values directly. What you want in the end with compared values ?

Comment: What @SharadChauhan said, compare the array, not the cells. If you must use the cells you can call `tableview.cellForRow(atIndexPath:)` to get the cell.

Comment: In the goal section shown towards the right, I'll be displaying 'up' and 'down' arrows accordingly...

Comment: You have an array with this data somewhere, in your cellForRow delegate method you access that array with the indexPath.row value, you can just use indexPath.row+1 to get the next element and use that one to compare the two. Be sure to check if you're not at the last cell, because then accessing the next element in the array will give a crash.

Comment: @SharadChauhan I have added the few lines of code I wrote in `cellForRowAtIndex..`

Comment: @kevin I'll try

Comment: @bwv Basically you want to sort the data based on your arrow selection. Can you post structure of you fitnessData Model.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs also @Sharad Chauhan. The other answer has worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if you're not at the last element and if not, get the next element in the array to compare against:

```
let fitnessData = fitnessDetails[indexPath.row]
cell.dateLabel.text = fitnessData.date
cell.dataLabel.text = fitnessData.value
if indexPath.row+1 < fitnessDetails.count {
    let nextFitnessData = fitnessDetails[indexPath.row+1]
    // icon = nextFitnessData.someValue > fitnessData.someValue ? ^ : v
}
```

What this does is when you create the layout for the cell, you take a sneak peek at the next element in line (the data of the cell below it, basically). You can use that data to determine the direction of your arrow. The check is important, because if you are already at the last element, trying to access the next one results in an out-of-bounds error.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @kevin. It worked...:) Have given an upvote also... :)Would you maybe mind explaining in a line or two as to what exactly was done..?